# Remove observations based on count of values within an ID column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe called `df` and i want to remove values races that have less than 2 dogs in the race. how can i do this?

input

```
race_id   dog_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         3
3         1
3         2
3         4
3         5
4         1
4         4
```

output

```
race_id   dog_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
3         1
3         2
3         4
3         5
```

i've tried

```
df.loc[lambda x:x.race_id.isin(df.groupby('race_id').dog_id.nunique().gt(2).index.tolist())]
```

but this didn't work? looking for a simpler solution nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: So you want to remove races with less or equal than 2 dogs, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I want to remove races with less than or equal to 2 dogs.

Comment: `groupby_transform` with `nunique` and then your count you want to keep with condition (lt, gt.eq)..

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df.loc[df.groupby("race_id")["dog_id"].transform("nunique").gt(2)])
```

Prints:

```
   race_id  dog_id
0        1       1
1        1       2
2        1       3
5        3       1
6        3       2
7        3       4
8        3       5
```